# TCP Packet drop on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: networking, wireshark, tcp

I'm trying to integrate a TCP offload (Which is currently a TCP loopback) in my system.
To do so, I have the core connected over Ethernet to a switch in the system.

I ran 3 different tests (using netcat), and got the following results:

1. Linux<->Core: Works fine. I send packets and receive them back.
2. Windows<->Core: **Doesn't work.**  I send the packets, and see them received back on wireshark. But no echo back on the netcat console
3. Windows<->Linux_loopback: Works fine.    (The linux Loopback was done by creating a FIFO, and then running "cat /home/fifo | netcat -l -p 5000 > /home/fifo".

Looking at the TCP capture, the only weird thing I see is one packet that has an ACK_Number with no ACK_Flag.

I'm trying to find out if this packet is the problem, and if not, What is the reason for the Windows netcat, not to show the echoed packets from the core.

Is the Linux TCP stack more permissive than the Windows one?

Thanks

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by `core`?  Is it the machine with a NIC that has TCP offload?  What does that machine runs?

Comment: It's an FPGA with an ethernet and tcp stack implementation, that currently supposed to send back every packet that it receive

Comment: I do not know an answer for that, but i'll share the way i'd approach it.  I'd try to get two `pcap`s for each connection (one on `core` and another on the connecting machine) then use `mergecap` to mere them chronologically.  Finally use `Statistics > Compare` in `wireshark` on the merged `pcap`.  Repeat this for the other machine vs. `core` and compare the statistics between the two merged `pcap`s.  Wireshark statistics often catch interesting patterns.